# Pandas : How to drop #DIV/0! and NA values in 'new' column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I did some calculation and have  #DIV/0! in my dataframe. How to drop these values and count further ? I followed df.dropna but dataframe still counting #DIV/0!. Please suggest.

```
df.insert(loc=df.columns.get_loc('A')+1 , 
          column = 'new', 
         value=(abs(df['A'] - df['B'])/df['B'] * 100))
df = df.dropna()
df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(len(df.index))
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please share some of your data, or a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You can tell your script to treat '#DIV/0!' as NaN values when you read your excel/csv file:

More here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', na_values=['#DIV/0!'])
```

Comment: its not the problem in reading CSV. I created new column in dataframe after reading csv.

Comment: @Akash - the `#DIV/0!` error is made by excel, not pandas. So the csv must have been used in excel at some point. This answer should convert the `#DIV/0!` to `np.nan` when you read the document. Then, you can remove the nan values with `df.dropna()`.