# how to drop excel zero division number

Tags: python

in excel, I calculate A/B, if B=0, it got #DIV/0!.  I copied all the data into pandas, then I used dropna() trying to remove #DIV/0!. However, it still has #DIV/0!. Is #DIV/0! different from NaN in pandas? Thanks

```
data=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t')
data=data.dropna(axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104339/pandas-how-to-drop-div-0-and-na-values-in-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe) answer to yours?

Comment: Yes Marte, it works as well, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following code for the dataframe:

```
data['column_to_replace value'] = data['column_to_replace value']\
    .apply(lambda x: x.replace('#DIV/0!', 0))]
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks Alex

Comment: @roudan Do not use a lambda function that loops. Pandas has a param to handle custom nan values. Just do `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', na_values='#DIV/0!')`

Comment: Thanks Chris, good comment!